# is it possible to run WebGpu on an Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, webgpu

I'm trying to run WebGpu on an Android emulator, (on M1 mac with Metal - 83.1, android sdk emulator version 31.3.10.0)

i've tried different emulators, with API 28-33,
and all the rendering option (renderer-maximum / swift-shaders / native-openGL).

the device logcat shows it's GLES version is 3.0.3.

if i request a device with `limits::downlevel_defaults()` (which is compatible with GLES-3.1), it fails as expected, with these errors:

`Error in Adapter::request_device: Limit 'max_vertex_buffers' value 8 is better than allowed 0`

or

`Error in Adapter::request_device: Limit 'max_compute_workgroups_per_dimension' value 65535 is better than allowed 0`

but even when requested with `limits::downlevel_webgl2_defaults` which [should be compatible with GLES-3.0](https://wgpu.rs/doc/wgpu/struct.Limits.html#impl-Limits)

i get errors:

`Error in Adapter::request_device: Limit 'max_inter_stage_shader_components' value 60 is better than allowed 0`

Why is this happening?

Is there any way i could create an emulator that is capable of running WebGPU?

Comment: Possibly related issue ticket: [WebGL is not supported in WebView in the Android emulator (works from Chrome in the same emulator)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37129533), key comment: `(Note: you might need to boot emulator from command line with the flag "-feature GLESDynamicVersion")`

Comment: tried now, got the same results as before :/

Comment: WebGPU currently requires Vulkan 1.1, not GLES. [WebGPU "Compatibility Mode"](https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb/issues/4266) is in development which will bring WebGPU to GLES 3.1 devices with some restrictions. As for whether either will run on emulators I don't know.